# wso2 bps how to fix bug in ode-dao-jpa-1.3.5-wso2v12.jar

Tags: wso2

I make some code change in ode-dao-jpa-1.3.5-wso2v12.jar, then create a new folder under patches, and put ode-dao-jpa-1.3.5-wso2v12.jar into new folder like patches\patch0006. In the patches.log, I found this is applied. But in runtime, I found my changes doesn't take effect. Is there any other places should I do?

```
[2016-01-21 15:12:23,829]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils} -  Applying - patch0006
[2016-01-21 15:12:23,844]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.server.util.PatchUtils} -  Patched ode-dao-jpa-1.3.5-wso2v12.jar(MD5:59f72bd01ea57109c8f97235027291b3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps you took to patch ode-dao-jpa library is wrong. In WSO2 BPS, we create a single ODE OSGI bundle by combining all ODE's sub projects.

https://github.com/wso2/wso2-ode/blob/master/orbit/pom.xml

This is the OSGI bundle you need to put in your patch folder.

1) Check your /repository/components/plugins/ode_1.3.5_wso2vX.jar

For BPS 3.5.0 this should be 1.3.5-wso2v15.

2) Checkout correct version from following locations.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/ode/

or

https://github.com/wso2/wso2-ode/ ( Check tag v1.3.5-wso2vX )

3) Do your fix in ode-dao-jpa. And build entire ode project.

4) If your working in Git, you can find new Ode single OSGI bundle in https://github.com/wso2/wso2-ode/tree/master/orbit folder.

4.b) If you are working in SVN location, build correct version in following location.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/orbit/ode/

5) Copy ode-1.3.5-wso2vX.jar jar to your patch folder.

Comment: Also, it is bug please free to create a Jira in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BPS and send your fix to https://github.com/wso2/wso2-ode/. So that we can review and merge your fix.

Comment: thanks a lot, this really help. My change take effect now.  My fixing is in BPS 3.2, and source code is not in Github yet.

Comment: Great, We always welcome contribution from community. If you feel, there is something is wrong or could have done in better way, Please feel free to report jira.